# How would I be able to place a VPython simulation display into a certain area of a PyQt5 GUI?

Tags: python, pyqt5, vpython

I'm building a 2D simple projectile motion simulation. I have the GUI layout on the PyQt5 side set (with buttons/dropdowns/checkboxes, but none work yet), and the VPython physics code set as well. I have a large area of the windowed application meant to show the screen (the same one that would pop up in a browser with only VPython code). I can't figure out how to connect the simulation visual to that portion of the window, so how would I do that? What widget should I use?

It's also worth mentioning that I am at an intermediate level with VPython and Python itself, but a complete beginner with PyQt5, so I've built the whole GUI in the Qt Designer.

I don't know if it's worth posting my code here as all of it is completely unmodified Qt Designer code with no references to VPython, but here's the code for the black box, which was placed in the UiMainWindow() class:

```
    self.simulation_view = QtWidgets.QOpenGLWidget(self.centralwidget)
    self.simulation_view.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(70, 10, 961, 541))
    self.simulation_view.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.ArrowCursor))
    self.simulation_view.setObjectName("simulation_view")
```

Here's a screenshot of the GUI, with the black box being an OpenGL widget (which is probably wrong for my case) where I want the simulation to appear:

[image: GUI image]

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that this won't work, because I might expect VPython's event loop and PyQt5's event loop would fight with each other. A different approach would be simply to use VPython's widgets, which includes buttons/dropdowns/checkboxes. I'll comment that for VPython questions it's better to post to the VPython forum, where there are many more VPython users who will see your question than if you post to stackoverflow:

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups&hl=en#!forum/vpython-users